# Not able to kill 2 activities at the same time. why is that?

Tags: android, pid

I'm trying to kill 2 activities on the onclick of a button. The current activity and the previous activity. Using their pids. I'm just able to kill one activity. Why does this happen?

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                android.os.Process.killProcess(pidofmain);
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

                }
```

If I see in my logcat, The activity with pid "pidofmain" is getting killed whereas the current activity is not getting killed.

"pidofmain" is an integer i received from the previous activity using an intent.

Comment: Why are you trying to kill your own app? Have you looked into the `finish()` method?

Answer (score 0):

Leave process killing to the OS. This is bad for any kind of program in a timesharing OS. If you want to conserve memory or something like that, let the OS handle it.
Also you can't really know if the process was correctly killed because well, if it is you wouldn't know, and if it doesn't you were not supposed to do it.
What do you want to do this for?

Answer (score 0):

A much better way to do this is to call `finish()` for the current activity. You can also signal the previous activity to finish if it calls the current activity using `startActivityForResult(Intent)`. The current activity would call `setResult(int)` before calling `finish()` to send a return code back to the previous activity. The previous activity can test the return code in `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` and also call `finish()` based on the result code.

Killing processes should be left to the OS. Once the activities finish, the will kill it off if it needs the resources. Otherwise it can let it around, which might help speed up a relaunch of your app if the user wants to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a definitive answer, but more like some thoughts that I have but it's too late for my to fire up Eclipse and prototype them.  If it doesn't help you let me know and I'll try to look into it deeper tomorrow night.

A few thoughts (I hope they help):
1) Android apps really are single-threaded, and your main activity controls all the dispatch events (including events to what I assume to be a second thread that you created).  If you kill the main activity, I'm pretty sure that your application would terminate execution immediately following your first call to `android.os.Process.killProcess(pidofmain)`, and you'd never make it to your second call because you would have killed your entire application. Again, this is assuming by the variable name pidofmain that you are killing the main UI thread and not just an activity called main.
2) I'm a little curious also about where you got pidofmain? It sounds like you have three activities total, and in the first activity you get it's process id and send it to the second activity in an intent bundle, which also gets passed along to a third activity (which is the place where you're trying to kill this whole thing)? If that is the case, and you're trying to kill the currently running activity, the table in the documentation here leads me to believe that you can't just kill an activity that's in the resumed state using the same method.  [Official Android Docs for Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)  You might want to try calling the finish() method for your currently running activity.

What exactly do you see in logcat?  And what happens in the UI? Does the visible activity continue to run, but the other activity has been removed from the backstack?